# what is the equivalent of register(Ansible) in Saltstack?

Tags: ansible, devops, salt-stack

In ansible we use register to holding the output of an external command
the question is what is the equivalent in Saltstack ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge and reading documentation, at the moment, there is no option to capture output from a state.

What you could do it write your own state and run the task you would like to capture the output and process/perform another task.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is not a one-to-one mapping for this it is however possible to do this in Saltstack:

```
{% set return = salt['cmd.run']('echo hello') %}
```

and then use the `return` variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options, but the most common would be to use the [`cmd.run`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cmdmod.html#salt.modules.cmdmod.run) execution function in a Jinja template.

If you need to capture data during state execution, rather than templating, then there is the [slots feature](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/slots).